# MySQL left join, error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, syntax-error

I have some problem with php left join

php write me a error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM ipb_topics t LEFT JOIN ipb_posts p ON p.topic_id = t.tid
>   LEFT JOIN ipb_at' at line 12

and the code is

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT

t.tid as tid,
t.title as title,
t.start_date as start_date,
t.title_seo as title_seo,

p.post as post,

a.attach_location as attach_location,

FROM ".$forum_prefix."topics t
LEFT JOIN ".$forum_prefix."posts p ON p.topic_id = t.tid
LEFT JOIN ".$forum_prefix."attachments a ON a.attach_rel_id = t.tid

GROUP BY t.tid
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comma at the end of your field clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT

t.tid as tid,
t.title as title,
t.start_date as start_date,
t.title_seo as title_seo,

p.post as post,

a.attach_location as attach_location

FROM ".$forum_prefix."topics t
LEFT JOIN ".$forum_prefix."posts p ON p.topic_id = t.tid
LEFT JOIN ".$forum_prefix."attachments a ON a.attach_rel_id = t.tid

GROUP BY t.tid
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Try this!! Don't forget to escape your data. Don't use `mysql_*` use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` Refer [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)